# Cannot run multiple animations on GroundOverlay [GoogleMap]

Tags: android, animation, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

I am trying to achieve a breathing effect animation on my MapFragment but for some reason, I cannot run multiple animations on the map. What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

[image]

And the circles are expanding gradually and fading away doing so. Right now my animation is doing this:

[image]

Which is not quite what I want. The current code (if I uncomment the 2 blocks with the handlers) is doing only one animation and the rest of the shapes are staying stationary. EDIT I found out what is going on - the "startAnimation" method is overriding the current animation. Now I am wondering if there is a way how I can avoid this overriding? Any ideas?:

[image]

This is my code:

```
   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

//Add smallest image drawable overlay

        mDotMarkerBitmap = generateBitmapFromDrawable(R.drawable.circle_drawable);
        groundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mDotMarkerBitmap))
                .position(xDesign, 100));
        groundAnimation = new RadiusAnimation(groundOverlay);
        groundAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        groundAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        groundAnimation.setDuration(2000);
        mapFragment.getView().startAnimation(groundAnimation); // MapView where i show my map
//TODO  Fix the animation tomorrow
//Add medium size image drawable overlay

//        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//                // your code here
//                mDotMarkerBitmap = generateBitmapFromDrawable(R.drawable.circle_drawable2);
//                groundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
//                        .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mDotMarkerBitmap))
//                        .position(xDesign, 100));
//                groundAnimation = new RadiusAnimation(groundOverlay);
//                groundAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
//                groundAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
//                groundAnimation.setDuration(10000);
//                mapFragment.getView().startAnimation(groundAnimation); // MapView where i show my map
//            }
//        }, 1000/* 1sec delay */);

//
////Add smallest size image drawable overlay
//        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
//        {
//            @Override
//            public void run()
//            {
//                // your code here
//                mDotMarkerBitmap = generateBitmapFromDrawable(R.drawable.circle_drawable3);
//                groundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
//                        .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mDotMarkerBitmap))
//                        .position(xDesign, 100));
//                groundAnimation = new RadiusAnimation(groundOverlay);
//                groundAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
//                groundAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
//                groundAnimation.setDuration(2000);
//                mapFragment.getView().startAnimation(groundAnimation); // MapView where i show my map
//            }
//        }, 1000/* 1sec delay */);



        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(xDesign, 15));
    }
```

circle_drawable.xml (circle_drawable2 and 3 are the same exept the width&height values, they are bigger 60 and 90dp and the colors - blue and red):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#0093e8"/>
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

RadiusAnimation class:

```
public class RadiusAnimation extends Animation {
    private GroundOverlay groundOverlay;

    public RadiusAnimation(GroundOverlay groundOverlay) {
        this.groundOverlay = groundOverlay;

    }
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        groundOverlay.setDimensions( (100 * interpolatedTime) );
        groundOverlay.setTransparency( interpolatedTime );

    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is trying to do something similar I found the solution. In order to run multiple animations at the same, I can use AnimationSet. So I removed the Handlers which were to delay the individual animations but since each one is overriding the last one it was not working and I was seeing the last one added playing on the mapFragment. So I changed my code like that:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


//Add smallest image drawable overlay

        Bitmap mDotMarkerBitmap1 = generateBitmapFromDrawable(R.drawable.circle_drawable);

        GroundOverlay groundOverlay1 = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mDotMarkerBitmap1))
                .position(xDesign, 100));

        groundAnimation = new RadiusAnimation(groundOverlay1);
        groundAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        groundAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        //        groundAnimation.setDuration(700);
        breadingAnimations.addAnimation(groundAnimation);


        Bitmap mDotMarkerBitmap2 = generateBitmapFromDrawable(R.drawable.circle_drawable2);
        GroundOverlay groundOverlay2 = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mDotMarkerBitmap2))
                .position(xDesign, 100));

        Animation groundAnimation2 = new RadiusAnimation(groundOverlay2);
        groundAnimation2.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        groundAnimation2.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        //        groundAnimation2.setDuration(900);
        breadingAnimations.addAnimation(groundAnimation2);


        Bitmap mDotMarkerBitmap3 = generateBitmapFromDrawable(R.drawable.circle_drawable3);
        GroundOverlay groundOverlay3 = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mDotMarkerBitmap3))
                .position(xDesign, 100));
        Animation groundAnimation3 = new RadiusAnimation(groundOverlay3);
        groundAnimation2.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        groundAnimation2.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        //        groundAnimation2.setDuration(1100);
        breadingAnimations.addAnimation(groundAnimation3);

        mapFragment.getView().startAnimation(breadingAnimations); // start animation


        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(xDesign, 15));
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve exact same animation as you mentioned. I used your code as a reference, but I am having some issues. I do not see the animation at all. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I am afraid that I no longer work for the same company, thus I no longer have access to the code I used. The code here is the only source I have to achieve the animation. I recall that it worked for me, though :)